# Manage a Thin server through a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

I have a project where I have a sinatra app and I want to launch it with thin through a admin ruby script file. I want to be able to start, stop and restart it, also being able to daemonize it if asked to. This is, I want to have something like this in my script:

#### bin/myscript

```
require 'MyCLI'
MyCLI.new(ARGV).run
```

#### lib/mycli.rb

```
class MyCLI
   # instantiate and other methods (inspired by thin runner)
   ...
   def run
      # parse commands and options 
      ...
      # then process command 
      case @command
         when 'start'
            @server = Thin::Server.new(host, port, MyModule::MyAppClass)
            @server.start 
         when 'stop'
            # ?
         when 'restart'
            # ?
         else
            raise "Unknown command"
      end
   end
end
```

But I'm struggling with some problems,

1. I need to daemonize it or not, depending on some command option and cant find if this is possible to do passing some parameter to `#new` after reading docs and digging in some of the code.
2. Stopping would be as easy as `@server.stop`, but as my script instantiates a mycli object at each command line request, I do not have a single object so @server vanishes after the start request, so I think that the only solution would be to control the PID (right??), but cant find how thin manages that. Also, running it in foreground would not work with this pid approach I presume.
3. What would be the proper way to restart it?

Has anyone a best solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried out god http://god.rubyforge.org/ ?

Comment: Hi, I want to shrink dependencies, so I would like to keep just the thin code. Is there a simple wait to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `qx` or `system` etc to call the command line client instead? I know it's not fancy, but it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up using Rack::Server.start(app, host, port, env, daemonize(Y/N), pid_file).

It works great, and it will pick up the thin handler if available.